# Kitchen Open Stack gives "excon.error.response"

Tags: chef-infra, openstack, test-kitchen

I have been trying to use Kitchen with Openstack. I did as described in this link https://github.com/test-kitchen/kitchen-openstack
When i do kitchen list it shows
`/root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fog-1.27.0/lib/fog/openstack/volume.rb:191: warning: duplicated key at line 196 ignored: :openstack_region
Instance          Driver     Provisioner  Last Action
default-centos-7  Openstack  ChefSolo     <Not Created>`

But when i do Kitchen test it gives

```
 -----> Cleaning up any prior instances of <default-centos-7>
-----> Destroying <default-centos-7>...
       Finished destroying <default-centos-7> (0m0.00s).
-----> Testing <default-centos-7>
-----> Creating <default-centos-7>...
>>>>>> Create failed on instance <default-centos-7>.
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/default-centos-7.log for more details
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: Expected([200, 204]) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)
excon.error.response
  :body          => "{\"error\": {\"message\": \"get_version_v2() got an unexpected keyword argument 'auth'\", \"code\": 400, \"title\": \"Bad Request\"}}"
  :headers       => {
    "Connection"     => "close"
    "Content-Length" => "121"
    "Content-Type"   => "application/json"
    "Date"           => "Wed, 04 Feb 2015 07:14:10 GMT"
    "Server"         => "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5"
    "Vary"           => "X-Auth-Token"
  }
  :local_address => "local IP"
  :local_port    => 43870
  :reason_phrase => "Bad Request"
  :remote_ip     => "remote IP"
  :status        => 400

>>>>>> ----------------------
```

Please tell me what is this error.

Here is my .kitchen.yml File

```
driver:
   name: openstack
   openstack_username: username
   openstack_api_key: key
   openstack_auth_url: url
   require_chef_omnibus: true
   server_name: newstack
   network_ref: public
   public_key_path: /opt/stack/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   private_key_path: /opt/stack/.ssh/id_rsa
   username: newuser
   password: newpassword
   port: 22
   key_name: pub
   openstack_tenant: newtenant
   openstack_region: RegionOne
   avaialability_zone: nova
   openstack_sevice_name: admin
   openstack_network_name: admin
   security_groups: default
   network_ref: public
   no_ssh_tcp_check: true
   no_ssh_tcp_check_sleep: true
   image_ref: [SERVER IMAGE ID]
   flavor_ref: [SERVER FLAVOR ID]
   disable_ssl_validation: true 

provisioner:
  name: chef_solo

platforms:

  - name: centos-7
    driver:
      name: openstack
      openstack_username: admin
      openstack_api_key: mypass
      openstack_auth_url:  <url>
      require_chef_omnibus: 'true'
      flavor_ref: 2
      image_ref: centos-7

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
      - recipe[openstackPOC::default]
    attributes:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem.

try openstack_auth_url: http://openstack_controller:35357/v2.0/ or http://openstack_controller:5000/v2.0/tokens

it worked for me :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution
for openstack_auth_url i had not given the token
So by giving it. It worked. 
Final Change
http://openstack_controller:5000/v2.0/tokens